# Is it possible to make code to download my own browsing history....?

Tags: web-applications, programming-languages, webserver

Is it possible to download my browsing history onto my computer and upload it to a webpage?

Essentially, I am trying to allow my friends to view my browsing history so they can follow what I read. In the long run, the idea is much bigger than just this, but I am hoping to understand the technical aspects behind this. I know it sounds like I'm trying to breach my own privacy but of course I would put some exceptions to the "user history" that I post on the web.

I'm hoping that this is possible with code, and if so, I'd really like to know the languages that I need to become familiar with. And if you are kind enough, please post your contact information below so that I could hope to catch you at a good time to ask even better questions.

Comment: Sometimes, there are simpler solutions than programming. For example: [delicious.com](http://www.delicious.com/)

Comment: @Cody Gray: delicious deals with bookmarks and not history, right?

Comment: @cherouvium: Yes, it deals with bookmarks. My point was that, rather than trying to build a program that exports bookmarks (which will be rather difficult), one could consider simply saving selected sites using a service like Delicious. This would still accomplish the same goal of being able to share them with friends. I realize it may not be the *perfect* solution, but I thought it was still worth suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and it would also (*) involve development of a browser plugin for every browser you'd like to support.

*: apart from the obvious web based application you'll need as the "home" and facilitator of your service.

Comment: Cherouvim, is there any way for a programmer to develop code that would be embedded in the website that wouldn't require the user to download a plugin? But instead, ask for permission?

Comment: For modern browsers there probably isn'y any way to do that. It would be a security issue. For IE you could maybe do it with ActiveX programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot cherouvim, appreciate the help !

Comment: Storing IE history Feels like useless for, atleast for me as the history would be consisting of only one item: http://www.google.com/chrome :P

Comment: @dcrodjer: The only website you've ever visited is the Chrome page? That's obviously false—don't look, but you're on www.stackoverflow.com now.

Comment: @Cody Gray. i forgot to mention IE in my comment, my usage of IE has been mostly only to download real browsers.